# Power BI DAX Count YM by the YM I selected in the filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure that counts the year month in my dataset

[image]

the dax is like this:

```
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE_NAME[YM]),
    FILTER(ALL(TABLE_NAME[YM]),TABLE_NAME[YM]<= MAX(TABLE_NAME[YM]))
    )
```

I would like it to change based on my filter, for example now if I choose 201908, 201909, 201910, it shows

[image]

I am looking for a way to make it be:

201908 1

201909 2

201910 3

if this works, when I choose 201907, 201908, 201909, 201910, it should be like:

201907 1

201908 2

201909 3

201910 4

I tried different ways but none of it works, please let me know if there's a way to solve it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your measure, you are using [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) function to remove any filters applied on your table. If your do want to obey these filters, then simply use [ALLSELECTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) instead:

```
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE_NAME),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(TABLE_NAME[YM]),TABLE_NAME[YM]<= MAX(TABLE_NAME[YM]))
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However I got an error message for this: 
A single value for column 'YM' in table 'Table_name' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Comment: Of course! I fixed the DAX - just use ALLSELECTED instead of ALL.